# CakePHP: auto-set model create and update dates

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

Is there a way to configure CakePHP models to automatically set timestamps, such as **created_on** and **updated_on**, when saving the object?

I'm thinking of an equivalent to Django's DateTimeField's **auto_now** and **auto_now_add** options.

I've heard this is a controversial practice in some frameworks, but I want to do it anyway.

If you *can't* do this, do people normally set the timestamps in the beforeSave() handlers, perhaps by checking if the model data already contains an id field and setting a creation data accordingly?

Thanks, and apologies if I've missed the relevant bit in the docs.

Comment: Thanks folks, 'created' and 'updated' are the magic field names.  All working good now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, CakePHP does this automagically for the fields `created` and `modified`.

In MySQL, the type for these fields should be DATETIME (or DATE) and NULLable.

Answer (score 3):

If you name your fields `created` and `modified` and make them of type `datetime`, Cake will handle the rest. http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#created-and-modified-1015

Answer (score 0):

Actually, use "now()" for updating datetime in mysql is simple and easy.

```
$updateField = array('last_login'=>'now()');
```